# installing pyopenssl on ios

Tags: ios, pyopenssl

when i type: easy_install pyopensll
the results are:

```
davie:~ root# easy_install pyopenssl
Searching for pyopenssl
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pyopenssl/
Reading http://pyopenssl.sourceforge.net/
Reading http://launchpad.net/pyopenssl
Best match: pyOpenSSL 0.13
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL- 0.13.tar.gz#md5=767bca18a71178ca353dff9e10941929
Processing pyOpenSSL-0.13.tar.gz
Running pyOpenSSL-0.13/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-faDtsb/pyOpenSSL-0.13/egg-dist-tmp-bvjmgV
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
In file included from OpenSSL/crypto/crypto.c:14:
/usr/include/python2.5/Python.h:18:20: error: limits.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/python2.5/Python.h:21:2: error: #error "Something's broken.  UCHAR_MAX should be defined in limits.h."
/usr/include/python2.5/Python.h:25:2: error: #error "Python's source code assumes C's unsigned char is an 8-bit type."
/usr/include/python2.5/Python.h:32:19: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/python2.5/Python.h:34:5: error: #error "Python.h requires that stdio.h define NULL."
/usr/include/python2.5/Python.h:37:20: error: string.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/python2.5/Python.h:39:19: error: errno.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/python2.5/Python.h:41:20: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/python2.5/Python.h:43:20: error: unistd.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/python2.5/Python.h:55:20: error: assert.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/include/python2.5/Python.h:57,
             from OpenSSL/crypto/crypto.c:14:
/usr/include/python2.5/pyport.h:7:20: error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/include/python2.5/Python.h:57,
             from OpenSSL/crypto/crypto.c:14: 
/usr/include/python2.5/pyport.h:73: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'Py_uintptr_t'
/usr/include/python2.5/pyport.h:74: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'Py_intptr_t'
/usr/include/python2.5/pyport.h:97: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'Py_ssize_t'
```

thats just one third of the results, does anybody know what I'm doing wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is pyOpenSSL, you can add [the iNinjas Cydia repo](http://ininjas.com/repo/) and install it from there.

It appears that you don't have a working C compiler installed on your device. This has always been problematic for me until I found the package called "Compile C Apps iOS4". It is in the iBeta section of [this repo](http://repo.insanelyi.com/)

After installing that, try to `easy_install` it again if you want to install it manually.